# Boost async_receive_from makes std::cin crash with buffer overflow

Tags: boost, udp, buffer, overflow

while coding a server supporting both TCP and UDP with the boost library, I encountered a strange problem: After the server receives any UDP message, a call of std::cin (or std::getline) will crash if I try to put the input into a string.

This does only happen after at least one UDP message was received. I have no idea what happens here, because I hardly do anything when receiving a message. I broke the important code down:

```
void AsynchronousServer::DoReceiveUDP()
{
    m_udp_socket.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(m_udp_receive_buffer,
      m_udp_receive_buffer.size()),
    udp::endpoint(), [this](boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t
      bytes_transferred)
    {
    });
}
```

The DoReceiveUDP() method is called right when the server is up and before io_service.run(). Usually it does a bit more (e.g. call itself again), but for testing purposes I commented everything out so that it really does nothing more than receive once. m_udp_receive_buffer is an

```
std::array<char, 8196>
```

, an attribute of the AsynchronousServer class that is not used anywhere else.

In the main thread, this is all I really do after setting up the server:

```
while(true)
{
    std::string message;
    std::getline(std::cin, message); //On this line the program crashes
    //server.SendMessageTCP(1, message);
}
```

Now as I said, the crash (debug message says buffer overflow) only happens after a message was received via UDP. My server also reads TCP messages via async_read. This does not provoke the error though.

I also tested this with storing the getline-input in an constant sized array, which works fine. But I cant really do that since I dont know how long the message is then, which means the buffer is filled with a lot of useless characters when I send the message. Besides, I dont really feel safe anyway with strange stuff like that happening and would rather solve the problem than bypass it.

Do any of you have some ideas on what could be the problem here? If you need more code, just ask, but I think I already posted everything relevant. :)

EDIT: I commented out the error code and bytes transferred too, but it is in the "full" version. I don't get any errors and bytes transferred is exactly the length of the message.

After some more tests I can at least guess a little more. The problem seems to occur if I am expected to enter input via cin and during this, a message is received.

E.g. if I do this:

```
while(true)
{
    std::string message;
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(3));
    std::getline(std::cin, message);
}
```

and the client sends a UDP message within this three seconds the thread sleeps, everything goes fine. If the three seconds pass and THEN the message is received, it crashes as before.

However, there is one really strange behaviour: After I sended a UDP message within these three seconds, the program won't crash anymore at all - even if I wait with the next message until the thread has reached getline again. I have no idea why that happens...

Comment: You aren't checking the error parameter in the async_receive_from handler. Similarly, how many bytes are received?

Comment: Yeah, I commented that out too but it is in the 'full' version. I don't get any error_code. Bytes received are exactly the length of the message.

Comment: you likely have an object lifetime issue, please post the definition of `AsynchronousServer`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I found a "solution" for this problem. I still don't know why it happens and if that is really a solution at all or whether I'll run into other problems later.

Also, I have no idea, why this solution works. :D

Anyway, it works if the buffer is not a member function but created anew for every call of ReceiveUDP:

```
void AsynchronousServer::DoReceiveUDP()
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::array<char, 8192>> udp_receive_buffer;

    m_udp_socket.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(*udp_receive_buffer, udp_receive_buffer->size()),
      udp::endpoint(), boost::bind<void>([this](boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t bytes_transferred,
    std::shared_ptr<std::array<char, 8192>> udp_receive_buffer)
    {
    }, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, udp_receive_buffer));
}
```